# Instant replay for sports

Tags: video, video-recording, sport

We hold historical fencing competitions where the hits are judged by referees. However, sometimes it is needed to evaluate a particular exchange using a video recording. Currently we do it with smartphones (a guy with a smartphone is moving around the arena and records the exchange and when required replays it to the referee).

I'm looking for a software that would do the same thing as the smartphone but on a computer. That means, it would grab video from a camera connected to the computer and and when required it would replay the last exchange. The benefit over the smartphone solution is that the computer might have larger display attached, or possibly stream this to the internet.

I'd like this software to be free and/or open source. If it runs on linux as weel it would be nice.